# EMACS mumamo/nxhtml mode is overriding js2-mode for js files

Tags: emacs

How do you choose which files mumamo loads on?  It is now the default for all files despite what I have in my .emacs file.

I'd like to use js2-mode when it's a js file, mumamo if it's html/php/etc.

Comment: Afaik it uses ``auto-mode-alist``. And I think ``js2-mode`` is not compatible with mumamo, so this is a tricky question.

Comment: I don't want to use them together, just limit mumamo to certain file types that it would be good at ie. html, php.  No compatibility needed there, right?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you contact the author, Lennart Borgman, directly.  He is usually quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I added the following lines in my .emacs:

```
;; js2-mode configuration
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))
;; because nxhtml-mode forces loading .js files with javascript-mode
(defalias 'javascript-mode 'js2-mode)
```